# JSON object from POST request in BaasBox

Tags: javascript, json, baasbox

I'm trying to create a JSON object from the payload in a POST request but can't seem to get it working. I'm using BaasBox and I've created a JavaScript plugin that looks like this:

```
http().post(function(req){
    Box.log(req.method + " received: " + req);
    var jsonObject = JSON(req.body);
    Box.log("JSON parsed successfully");

    var message = new Object();
    message.message = jsonObject["message"];
    message.firstname = jsonObject["firstname"];
    message.lastname = jsonObject["lastname"];

    var doc = Box.Documents.save("Messages",message);
    Box.log("Messages created: " + doc.id);
    return {status: 200, content: message};
});
```

It's a simple script that attempts to create a JSON object from the request body. The JSON from the iOS client application looks like this:

```
let json = "{ \"firstname\" : \"John\" , \"lastname\" : \"Jones\" , \"message\" : \"Hello there\" }"
```

Now here's the interesting part: If I just store the request body like this instead, then the JSON is successfully stored as a Document.

```
http().post(function(req){
    Box.log(req.method + " received: " + req);

    var doc = Box.Documents.save("Messages",req.body);
    Box.log("Messages created: " + doc.id);
    return {status: 200, content: req.body};
});
```

How can I create a JSON object from the request body?

Comment: try changing `var jsonObject = JSON(req.body);` to `var jsonObject = JSON.parse(req.body);`

Comment: Whoops, mistype from my side! But that doesn't work :(

Comment: have you tried `var doc = Box.Documents.save("Messages",JSON.stringify(message));` ?

Comment: I was playing around with this for a while and found that the req.body wasn't actually a string. So I used that stringify method to turn it into a string and now it works. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the req.body wasn't an actual string. Here's the updated code that works:

```
http().post(function(req){
    Box.log(req.method + " received: " + req);
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    Box.log("JSON parsed successfully");

    var message = new Object();
    message.message = jsonObject["message"];
    message.firstname = jsonObject["firstname"];
    message.lastname = jsonObject["lastname"];

    var doc = Box.Documents.save("Messages",message);
    Box.log("Messages created: " + doc.id);
    return {status: 200, content: message};
});
```